# How to switch the position of PACS and keywords in revtex 4

Tags: positioning, revtex

I am trying to submit a paper to a journal where they want to display the keywords before the PACS numbers. The template I have used is the revtex4, I have tried almost everything to make the keywords appear before the PACS without any success, can you please advise me on this issue. This is a copy of my coding:

```
\documentclass[jkps,preprint,fleqn,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumitem}  

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\title[]{atomic beam experiment}
\author{1st author}
\email{auth.@email.com}
\author{2nd author}
%\thanks{Fax: +82-2-554-1643}
\affiliation{Department of Physics}

\date[]{ September 2016}

\begin{abstract}
 *******************
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Atom beam experiment; qubit manipulation; Rb atom beam}

\pacs{42.50.Ex, 32.80.Wr, 32.80.-t; 32.10.Fn}

%the [jkps] is the journal of Korean physical society 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a small compilable LaTeX document that shows your problem  (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`). It is impossible to analyze your problem and propose an adequate solution without knowing your precise setup. Use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/332396/edit) left below your posting to add the source code.

Comment: thank you, i have now added the code, i appreciate your help very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the journal editors' duty to provide the proper style file. If they don't and just ask you to use whatever class you like, you can fix the order for PACS and keywords in the following way.

```
\documentclass[preprint,fleqn,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% the macro for printing the PACS adds a vertical space before them
\patchcmd\frontmatter@PACS@format{\addvspace{11\p@}}{}{}{}% remove the space
% add the vertical space before the keywords
\pretocmd\frontmatter@keys@format{\addvspace{11\p@}}{}{}
% switch the positions between PACS and keywords
\patchcmd{\titleblock@produce}
  {\@pacs@produce\@pacs\@keywords@produce\@keywords}
  {\@keywords@produce\@keywords\@pacs@produce\@pacs}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title[]{atomic beam experiment}
\author{1st author}
\email{auth.@email.com}
\author{2nd author}
%\thanks{Fax: +82-2-554-1643}
\affiliation{Department of Physics}

\date[]{ September 2016}

\begin{abstract}
 *******************
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Atom beam experiment; qubit manipulation; Rb atom beam}

\pacs{42.50.Ex, 32.80.Wr, 32.80.-t; 32.10.Fn}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you ever so much, this has now solved my problem..... i am grateful to all your help

Answer (score 0):

The complete header, including keywords, is only typeset when the command `\maketitle` is executed, see below.  The keywords will appear *after* PACS, but don't try to change this (your write that you want them to appear *before*) since the order is defined by the publisher, not by the author. As a side-note, you don't have to reset the `page` counter, this is done automatically.

```
\documentclass[jkps,preprint,fleqn,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4}
\begin{document}

\title[]{atomic beam experiment}
\author{1st author}
\email{auth.@email.com}
\author{2nd author}
\affiliation{Department of Physics}
\date[]{ September 2016}
\begin{abstract}
  A paper on atomic beam experiments.
\end{abstract}
\keywords{Atom beam experiment; qubit manipulation; Rb atom beam}
\pacs{42.50.Ex, 32.80.Wr, 32.80., 32.10.Fn}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are using the right document class for the journal.  The `revtex` class is designed for journals of the American Physical Society, however, you want to submit to the Journal of the Korean Physical Society.  That is why `revtex` does not recognize the option `jkps` and reports in the log

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [jkps].
```

It is still possible to switch the order of PACS and keywords.  Therefore I copied the definition of the title macro from `revtex4.cls` and switched around the lines `\@keywords@produce\@keywords` and `\@pacs@produce\@pacs`.

```
\documentclass[preprint,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4}

\makeatletter
\def\titleblock@produce{%
 \begingroup
  \let\footnote\footnote@latex
  \let\@makefnmark\@makefnmark@latex
  \let\@footnotemark\@footnotemark@latex
  \let\thefootnote\frontmatter@thefootnote
  \global\c@footnote\z@
  \let\@makefnmark\frontmatter@makefnmark
  \frontmatter@setup
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}\label{FirstPage}%
  \frontmatter@title@produce
  \groupauthors@sw{%
   \frontmatter@author@produce@group
  }{%
   \frontmatter@author@produce@script
  }%
  \frontmatter@RRAPformat{%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@date}%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@received}%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@revised}%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@accepted}%
   \expandafter\produce@RRAP\expandafter{\@published}%
  }%
  \frontmatter@abstract@produce
  \@keywords@produce\@keywords
  \@pacs@produce\@pacs
  \par
  \frontmatter@finalspace
 \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Atomic Beam Experiment}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\email{email@example.com}
\affiliation{Department of Physics}

\begin{abstract}
\input lorem
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Atom beam experiment; qubit manipulation; Rb atom beam}

\pacs{42.50.Ex, 32.80.Wr, 32.80.-t; 32.10.Fn}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]