# Removing PACS and keywords field from latex template

Tags: titles, templates, revtex, preamble

I am using the same template as given in this post here:
[How to switch the position of PACS and keywords in revtex 4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332396/how-to-switch-the-position-of-pacs-and-keywords-in-revtex-4)

Here is the code reproduced for convenience:

```
  \documentclass[jkps,preprint,fleqn,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \usepackage{enumitem}  

 \begin{document}
 \setcounter{page}{0}     
 \title[]{atomic beam experiment}
 \author{1st author}
 \email{auth.@email.com}
 \author{2nd author}
 %\thanks{Fax: +82-2-554-1643}
 \affiliation{Department}

 \date[]{ September 2016}

 \begin{abstract}
 *******************
 \end{abstract}

 \keywords{Atom beam experiment; qubit manipulation; Rb atom beam}

 \pacs{42.50.Ex, 32.80.Wr, 32.80.-t; 32.10.Fn}

 %the [jkps] is the journal of Korean physical society 
 \end{document}
```

I would like to completely remove the pacs and keywords fields without modifying the style file (the other question requested a switch of the fields only).

Is it easy to do?

Comment: You have `showkeys,showpacs` in your options for revtex4. This obvious thing would be to remove those. Does that not work? Your code doesn't have a `\maketitle` command so I don't get anything with that code, but they are not there if I remove those options and use `\maketitle`. I also get a warning that the jkps option is undefined, so I may be missing something you have in your template, or using a different version.

Comment: @frabjous Thank you, problem resolved